# AutoDocString for Powershell functions

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

Do we have any VScode extension similar to https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=njpwerner.autodocstring or any other way for providing auto doc string for PowerShell functions?
Currently I've to add the doc string manually like this :

```
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        A brief description of the function or script.

    .DESCRIPTION
        A longer description.

    .PARAMETER FirstParameter
        Description of each of the parameters.
        Note:
        To make it easier to keep the comments synchronized with changes to the parameters,
        the preferred location for parameter documentation comments is not here,
        but within the param block, directly above each parameter.

    .PARAMETER SecondParameter
        Description of each of the parameters.

    .INPUTS
        Description of objects that can be piped to the script.

    .OUTPUTS
        Description of objects that are output by the script.

    .EXAMPLE
        Example of how to run the script.

    .LINK
        Links to further documentation.

    .NOTES
        Detail on what the script does, if this is needed.

    #>
```

Comment: Type `##` on top of a function. It will autogenerate a documentation block similar to the one you show above.  This is built-in in the powershell extension.

Comment: Ohh nice, it worked. I tried // but missed trying ##. 
Anyways thanks a ton.!

Comment: @SagePourpre you can add an Answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @SagePourpre Do you know if it is possible to update a documentation block when I change the function signature, e. g. add parameters? I can type `##` again, but then I have to copy-paste the changes and delete the remainder.

Comment: @zett42 Not that I am aware. For the few times I used comment-based help, I did as you describe. You could implement that programmatically by traversing the file using AST and updating the comment based help if needed. Personally, I don't really like comment-based help at all as it fluff up a lot of the code. I prefer the alternative, the ps1XML. Ps1xml is a pain though, unless you use PlatyPS to generate your doc.

Comment: @zett42 It generate a markdown documentation and also the PS1XML file. It auto-update the PS1XML based on the markdown updates and auto-update the markdown if you add / remove parameters and / or functions. See an example [here](https://github.com/itfranck/ConfluenceAtlassian/blob/main/Help/README.md). That way, you get your integrated help, you get an online friendly help too, to which you can bind directly in your code using the ` [CmdletBinding(HelpUri = 'https://something` syntax. IMO, the best of all worlds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is built-in with the PowerShell extension!

You can simply type `##` the line above a function. It will auto-expand into a comment-based help block which does account for the current defined parameters.

Comment: A handy feature indeed. I wish it worked with _scripts_ too (above the `param(...)` block), but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @mklement0 agreed. A workaround is to type `function asdf {` above the script param then type ## above that, you don't even need the closing bracket.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the method described in the accepted answer, but it did not work for me. I suggest one of two alternatives:

**Alternative 1:**

Use the tip from this article:
[How to Create Descriptive PowerShell Comments](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-comment/)

It works very well. Just type

```
comment-help
```

in Visual Studio Code and it works just fine.

**Alternative 2:**

Create your own user snippet in VSCODE.

Press `F1` or `CTRL+SHIFT+P` and type `Snippets: Configure User Snippets`.

Choose PowerShell. The contents of the file should be something like this:

```
{
    // File location:
    // C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\snippets
    "Document PowerShell code": {
        "prefix": "doc",
        "body": [
            "<#",
            ".SYNOPSIS",
            "    ${1:Short description}",
            ".DESCRIPTION",
            "    ${2:Long description}",
            ".PARAMETER <ParamenterName>",
            "    ${3:Parameter description}",
            ".OUTPUTS",
            "    ${4:Return description}",
            ".NOTES",
            "    Information or caveats about the function e.g. 'This function is not supported in Linux'",
            ".LINK",
            "    # Link description",
            "    http://www.fabrikam.com/extension.html",
            ".EXAMPLE",
            "    PS> extension -name \"File\"",
            "    File.txt",
            "#>"
        ],
        "description": "Template documentation block."
    }
}
```

You should, of course, *customize to your needs.*

After you save, it should be located at

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\snippets
```

Now, when you type **doc** (specified in the `"prefix": "doc",` line) it appears in the interface for selection.